# showing fps on swf flash file

Tags: flash, frame-rate

i m developing a gaming site which includes flash games.
i there any possible way to show the fps rate of those game?
i dont have the original fla file.
thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try mrdoob's [hi-res-stats](https://github.com/mrdoob/Hi-ReS-Stats).

```
//import into first frame or main as:

import src.net.hires.debug.Stats;

addChild( new Stats() );
```

[image: fps]